# How to properly calculate amount of fee in this smart contract?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, ether, contract-debugging, fees

I'm exploring `tradeBalances` method of [this smart contract](https://github.com/etherdelta/smart_contract/blob/master/etherdelta.sol#L265) and trying to investigate how does fee actually calculate for [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x48332867933b2d06e1fe38923f8501dcf3b2d3c6e21d012b562a510a5417a5e9) with the following decoded input data:

```
‌[
    "0xac709fcb44a43c35f0da4e3163b117a17f3770f5",
    "2500000000000000000000",
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "13775000000000000000",
    "3156959",
    "3696351802",
    "0xd8eeda4ee2657bb267bc35c1d60babdc5aedd269",
    "28",
    "b4bf0dcd37ca73bd5abce9532b033dcc6427be160683de113efca41320c27f3e",
    "78799d84040e5c245828b1b531ef97e1af124946f4dc1db5a20cf28a7073b269",
    "726181804936299500000"
]
```

As far I see from the calculation of fee:

```
tokens[tokenGet][feeAccount] = safeAdd(tokens[tokenGet][feeAccount], safeSub(safeAdd(feeMakeXfer, feeTakeXfer), feeRebateXfer));
```

I get:

```
// fee constants
const feeMake = '0';
const feeTake = '3000000000000000';

// amout fee calculation
let feeMakeXfer = (726181804936299500000 * 0) / (1 ether); // 0 ETH
let feeTakeXfer = (726181804936299500000 * 3000000000000000) / (1 ether); // 2.1785... ETH

// fee calculation
let fee = (feeMakeXfer + feeTakeXfer) - feeRebateXfer; // 2.1785... ETH
```

As result of calculations above I get `fee` as `2.1785... ETH` which I believe is very big in this case because amount of ETH he is buying according to [formula](https://github.com/etherdelta/smart_contract/blob/master/etherdelta.sol#L262) is:

```
let amount = (13775000000000000000 * 726181804936299500000) / 2500000000000000000000; // 4.001261... ETH
```

What I'm doing wrong? Please point to my mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`feeMake` and `feeTake` are denominated in the same currency as `amount`. `amount` in this case is denominated in `0xac709fcb44a43c35f0da4e3163b117a17f3770f5` which is a token not ether. Thus 2.1785 is the fee in tokens.

When calculating the fee they divide by `1 ether` however it doesn't mean that the fee itself is in ether, they just do it to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Is it possible to get `fee` in ether?

Comment: @Erik you mean to convert the fee into ether? I think it will be `feeTakeXfer * priceOfTokenInEther` where `priceOfTokenInEther = amountGive / amountGet`

Comment: could you please help me with this question please https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39957/how-to-calculate-number-of-eth-that-got-bought-in-transaction-by-trading