# How to calculate number of ETH that got bought in transaction by trading?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, ether

Let's say I have the following decoded transaction input data:

```
‌[
    "0xac709fcb44a43c35f0da4e3163b117a17f3770f5",
    "2500000000000000000000",
    "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "13775000000000000000",
    "3156959",
    "3696351802",
    "0xd8eeda4ee2657bb267bc35c1d60babdc5aedd269",
    "28",
    "b4bf0dcd37ca73bd5abce9532b033dcc6427be160683de113efca41320c27f3e",
    "78799d84040e5c245828b1b531ef97e1af124946f4dc1db5a20cf28a7073b269",
    "726181804936299500000"
]
```

that's used in `trade` method of [this smart contract](https://github.com/etherdelta/smart_contract/blob/master/etherdelta.sol#L252).

In this invoke the sender is willing to buy `ETH` by selling `ARC` ([0xac709fcb44a43c35f0da4e3163b117a17f3770f5](https://etherscan.io/token/0xac709fcb44a43c35f0da4e3163b117a17f3770f5)).

According to `trade` arguments and transaction's `input` data my calculations are:

```
let priceOfTokenInEther = 13775000000000000000 / 2500000000000000000000; // 0.00551
let eth = priceOfTokenInEther * 726181804936299500000 / 1000000000000000000; // 4.0012617451990105
```

So my result is `4.0012617451990105 ETH` was bought by trading `ACR` token.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your formulas and calculations look correct.

Comment: thanks a lot for all your answers. I have one more question about calculations. Could you please help me again ? :))) https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40000/how-to-calculate-exchange-fee-in-eth-in-transaction

Comment: sure, glad to help!