# How to calculate exchange fee in ETH in transaction?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, ether, fees

Let's say I have the following decoded transaction input data:

```
[
  "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "690000000000000000",
  "0xac709fcb44a43c35f0da4e3163b117a17f3770f5",
  "69000000000000000000",
  "3157593",
  "3268274872",
  "0x7d7a96a720396bb22681578545c56899f23f58e3",
  "27",
  "bdc6f8d14ade98f529d06fa1b1e85a9deb19df7a1621cc561a5167286d143885",
  "74e1206d9bdd7e39fad74991ad630fc424af1e34bf3c788aa22ac505804b9bd5",
  "100000000000000000"
]
```

that's used in `trade` method of [this smart contract](https://github.com/etherdelta/smart_contract/blob/master/etherdelta.sol#L252).

In this invoke the sender is willing to buy `ARC` ([0xac709fcb44a43c35f0da4e3163b117a17f3770f5](https://etherscan.io/token/0xac709fcb44a43c35f0da4e3163b117a17f3770f5)) token by selling `ETH`.

What I'm trying to calculate is how much `ETH` will be send to `feeAccount`; [This line of code](https://github.com/etherdelta/smart_contract/blob/master/etherdelta.sol#L276):

```
tokens[tokenGet][feeAccount] = safeAdd(tokens[tokenGet][feeAccount], safeSub(safeAdd(feeMakeXfer, feeTakeXfer), feeRebateXfer));
```

My calculations are:

```
const web3 = require('web3');

const feeMake = '0';
const feeTake = '3000000000000000';

let feeMakeXfer = (100000000000000000 * feeMake) / web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether'); // 0
let feeTakeXfer = (100000000000000000 * feeTake) / web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether')); // 300000000000000
let feeRebateXfer = 0;

let accountFee = feeMakeXfer + feeTakeXfer - feeRebateXfer; // 0.0003 ETH
```

So based on my calculations account fee for this trade is `0.0003 ETH`.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your calculations look correct again.